# Several asynctask or only one?

Tags: java, android, performance

I create a code that analyzes the audio signal, I divided it into 4 parts:

- An AsyncTask that recovers audio from the microphone via AudioRecord.
- An AsyncTask that applies an FFT and normalizes the signal
- And one last AsyncTask that creates the signal graph.
- All this is controlled via a class.

Knowing that everything is linked via blockingqueue to transmit the data between them.

The best is to decompose each part into several AsyncTask or into one?
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: are those tasks expected to run in paralel?

Comment: No, but doing so allows a more fluid signal display.

Answer (score 1):

As it is seen from the requirement, all operations are connected. So all should be done in one AsyncTask. But, I recommend you to use coroutines for this purpose as AsyncTask is deprecated now.

Comment: I'll try, because everything in the same Asynctask doesn't suit me, and it slows down the whole process.